# Apache NiFi: store binary data in flowfiles properties

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am developing an Apache NiFi processor which reads binary data from the incoming flowfiles. However I need two different binary blob from each flowfile. Do you know if there is a way to store binary data in the properties of the flowfiles, or a way to read the property as a String without destroying it with the encoding?

I am still interested if there is a solution to store a binary data in the processor config.

Thanks!

Comment: you can try to use base64 encoding/decoding to conbert binary data to string and back. but beware of storing large values in attributes because flowfile attributes are located in memory.

Comment: but why do you need that? why not to split data into two different flowfiles? or put some boundary between two parts?

Answer (score 0):

You can base64 encode the data and store it that way. However, you shouldn't do this sort of thing because flowfile attributes are stored in memory.